# Why does 'redeclare package medium=medium' not work when extending from DynamicPipe in OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am new to Modelica and currently trying extending a new model from Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe using OpenModelica. I have seen that other people were also struggeling with its compatibility to Modelica.Media. I have tried two ways of extending the DynamicPipe class. The first attempt was:

```
within MyClass;

model Mypipe
  extends Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe(redeclare package Medium = Medium);
  replaceable package Medium=Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater;
equation
  annotation(Icon(coordinateSystem(grid = {2, 8})));
end Mypipe;
```

With ended up with compliling errors. The second attempt worked:

```
within MyClass;

model Mypipe
  extends Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe(redeclare package Medium = MyMedium);
  replaceable package MyMedium=Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater;
equation
  annotation(Icon(coordinateSystem(grid = {2, 8})));
end Mypipe;
```

Many example models succesfully implement media redeclaration using the `(redeclare package Medium=Medium)` way. Why doesn't this work when extending from DynamicPipe in my code sample?

Thank you for helping me understanding how Modelica works.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in OpenModelica. I'll open a ticket about it.
It also works using:

```
model Mypipe
  extends Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater);
equation
  annotation(Icon(coordinateSystem(grid = {2, 8})));
end Mypipe;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and opening a ticket about it.

Comment: Adrian, please post the ticket reference for this bug.

Comment: https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/3833
It seems I forgot to open one (I think we already have it as some duplicate) so I opened a new one.